# Making manually-added choices available to other users in a SharePoint List (Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, choice-field

I have a list which is being fed by direct entry plus forms. One of the fields "Underlying technologies" allows multiple values and also manual entry of values. Everyone can add the values without an issue but those are not then available to others to use (they appear in white in the list and are not added to the choices).

This restricts the usefulness of the column for data analysis. I have searched a bit to find a solution and as a result restricted the column to a single choice only, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

I seem to be using the new SharePoint Online as there is an option to return to classic SharePoint.

Comment: Unfortunately, not possible with SharePoint out of the box functionalities. You may need to use some custom solution for this (maybe Power automate flow). Run a flow on item creation/update (or scheduled flow once in a day) > check if any choice entered (manually) not available in column choices > add such choices to column choices using API call.